# Error while implementing smart pointer class

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am stuck at a single error. Here is my code:

```
 template<class t>
 class smart_ptr{
    t *ptr;
 public: 
    smart_ptr(t *p):ptr(p){cout<<"smart pointer copy constructor is called"<<endl;} 

    ~smart_ptr(){cout<<"smart pointer destructor is called"<<endl;delete(ptr);}
    t& operator *(){cout<<"returning the * of pointer"<<endl;return(*ptr);}
    t* operator ->(){cout<<"returning the -> of pointer"<<endl;return(ptr);}
    t* operator=(const t &lhs){ptr=lhs;cout<<"assignement operator called"<<endl;}
   };
   class xxx{
            int x;
    public:
            xxx(int y=0):x(y){cout<<"xxx constructor called"<<endl;}
            ~xxx(){cout<<"xxx destructor is called"<<endl;}
            void show(){cout<<"the value of x="<<x<<endl;}
    };
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    xxx *x1=new xxx(50);
    smart_ptr<xxx *> p1(x1);
    return 0;
 }
```

While compilation I am getting below error

smart_pointer_impl.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:

smart_pointer_impl.cpp:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘smart_ptr::smart_ptr(xxx*&)’

smart_pointer_impl.cpp:7: note: candidates are: smart_ptr::smart_ptr(t*) [with t = xxx*]

smart_pointer_impl.cpp:4: note:                 smart_ptr::smart_ptr(const smart_ptr&)

Any help for a solution is most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change ::

```
smart_ptr<xxx *> p1(x1); to smart_ptr<xxx> p1(x1);
```

it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably `smart_ptr` is `template<class t>` and then in the main there was intended to be `smart_ptr<xxx>` instead of `smart_ptr<xxx*>`?

Answer (score 0):

You've not declared your class `smart_ptr` as a template

```
template <TYPE>
class smart_ptr{
    TYPE *ptr;
public: 
    smart_ptr(TYPE *p):ptr(p){cout<<"smart pointer copy constructor is called"<<endl;} 

    ~smart_ptr(){cout<<"smart pointer destructor is called"<<endl;delete(ptr);}
    TYPE& operator *(){cout<<"returning the * of pointer"<<endl;return(*ptr);}
    TYPE* operator ->(){cout<<"returning the -> of pointer"<<endl;return(ptr);}
    TYPE* operator=(const TYPE &lhs){ptr=lhs;cout<<"assignement operator called"<<endl;}
};
```

Also, you're declaring your pointer as of type 'pointer to xxx' but your template class is of a pointer to the type. Try:

```
smart_ptr<xxx> p1(x1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have, I hope, forgotten the first line of your code, that being

```
 template<class t>
```

and this line:

```
smart_ptr<xxx *> p1(x1);
```

should be:

```
smart_ptr<xxx> p1(x1);
```